# AssertionError: Expected a `date`, but got a `datetime`. Refusing to coerce, as this may mean losing timezone information

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am facing some issues while creating an API

Here is my model

```
class Education(AuditFields):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    school = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    field_of_study = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    start_year = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    end_year = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
```

This is my serializer :

```
class EducationSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Education
        fields = '__all__'
```

views :

```
class EducationCreateView(CreateAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset_list = Education.objects.filter(
            user=self.request.user)

        return queryset_list
    serializer_class = EducationSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

If I am post something it shows the following message

```
{
    "user": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

if I change my serializer like this

```
class EducationSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Education
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {'user': {'required': False}}
```

I am getting an error like this

> Expected a `date`, but got a `datetime`. Refusing to coerce, as this may mean losing timezone information. Use a custom read-only field and deal with timezone issues explicitly.

How to resolve this .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is because of the two fields in model: `start_year` and `end_year`

You have defined them to be of `date` type but assigning a `datetime` value as default.

Try to modify the two fields in model as given and also import datetime:

```
import datetime

    start_year = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    end_year = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 8):

You can try to explicitly define fields for serializer:

```
class EducationSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    start_year = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%d")
    end_year = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%d")
    ...
```